# TypeError: useContext(...) is undefined useloction()

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a react app. I want to use useLocation but it is throwing this error

TypeError: useContext(...) is undefined

My code

```
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from 'framer-motion'
function App() {
const location = useLocation();
return (
<div className="app">
  <Router>
    <Switch >
      <AnimatePresence exitBeforeEnter>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        <Route path='/about' component={About} />
        <Route path='/projects' component={Projects} />
        <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
        <Route path='/resume' component={Resume} />
      </AnimatePresence>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with that location? are you trying to get router information or just url information (which you can use `window.location`

Comment: The `useLocation` hook requires the context provided by `Router`. As you are using `useLocation` higher in the component tree than `Router` it can not find the required context.

Comment: try importing `import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom"` and wrap your export like `export default withRouter(App)`

Comment: @azium I am using it with frame-motion I want to the pathname

Comment: then just do `window.location.pathname` don't need any fancy extra utils

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to access useLocation outside switch/route components.